# Get the mode values of a column

Tags: php, mysql, mode

I have a table (sample below) which contains results from a phone vote

```
Number  Voted 
 97867  Dog
 97868  Cat
 97869  Dog
 97870  Dog
 97871  Cat
 97872  Donkey
```

I query the data using

```
  $stmt =   $pdo->query( "SELECT * from data_mobile_api  " )  ;
  $voting = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

What I want to do is get the most votes for a particular animal (The winners is etc) , however I would need to do this dynamically as the response from the text could be anything . So far I have pulled all the data into an array

```
  $animal = $voting['Voted']
  $votes[$animal] += 1
```

What I have is an array of $votes but I dont know how I can get the animal with the highest response,

Can anyone offer a way to do this or any better solution please ? hope all this all makes sense , thanks

Comment: . . What you are asking for is not the mode.  The mode is the most frequent value.  You should remove the tag from the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let mysql do the job:

```
$sql = "SELECT Voted, COUNT(Number) FROM table GROUP BY Voted";
```